# Как сделать xml с параметрами?

Tags: xml, php

Как можно реализовать такую опцию просмотр данных пользователя в формате XML при переходе по ссылке /users.xml?e=email&p=password (где email и password соответсвующие значения из таблицы пользователей)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, начнём с файла .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ some-page.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Теперь все запросы перенаправляются в файл some-page.php.
После этого стоит создать шаблон представления для xml-файла, т.е.примерно представить как у нас будет выглядеть конечный xml. Например

```
<user>
  <email>$email</email>
  <password>$password</password>
</user>
```

Ну или же придумать свою структуру. После этого, мы можем приступить к формированию xml.
Так как по-умолчанию передаётся формат text\html, а нам нужен text\xml, сообщим об этом браузеру заголовком:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml");?>
```

Далее в коде нам необходимо подставить данные из GET массива в шаблон и вывести на страницу. В итоге, мы получим что-то вроде

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml");
$email = $_GET['e'];
$pass = $_GET['p'];
$template = " <user>
  <email>$email</email>
  <password>$password</password>";
echo template;
?>
```